# HTML code not recognized just printed when working with localhost and php

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm working in php&localhost with a database and I'm tying to input something taken from a form but I encountered a first problem, my html code is not recognized, it's just printed. I tried including this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
<body>

<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this: 
`<?php
include 'inputForm.php';
...
?>`

Comment: How do u mean, its no recognized?

Comment: @DarkBee "html code is not recognized, it's just printed". To me it seems to mean that the raw code is output as text. Could this be a MIME type mismatch? (text/plain instead of text/html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the content header is somehow being malformed. Try putting this at the start of your php file:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html'); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

According to your question, you are trying to include that html file. Or at least that's what I get from where you say this:

```
include 'inputForm.php';
```

try this instead of using include on the file:

```
echo file_get_contents("inputForm.php");
```